# SMDK v1.7 for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, motorola-emdk

I am writing an application that uses the Symbol MC5040 barcode scanner. The problem is that I can't find the SMDK for .NET anywhere. All the download links are broken. I know it's very old but can someone help. Perhaps you can send it to me if you have it. Even if you don't have the exact version that would be ok. I can't use the EMDK from Motorola because I tried it and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR;

**edit:** Seems that the Motorola Solution portal removed all the older Symbol developer tools. I cannot find anywhere else these packages.

### Longer answer

Symbol has been acquired by Motorola in 2008 and moved into Motorola Solutions in 2011. In 2014, what was Symbol, has been acquired by Zebra Technologies.
This is why when you've a Symbol or a Motorola or a Motorola Solutions rugged device, you can find support downloads on Zebra support website.

The current SDK are called EMDK (Enterprise Mobility Development Kit) are available for the supported devices. MC5040 is no more supported since a very long time and this is why you can find support for it only in the older SMDK.

**Disclaimer: I work for Zebra Technologies**

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find smdk v1.7 on the same site. The problem I am having now is getting it to work. I did everything in the example but it doesn't enable the scanner.

Comment: Keep in mind that MC5040 is no more sold since 2009 and support ended in 2014. It's probably not trivial to bring together all the needed pieces (PPC2003 SDK, VisualStudio and the SMDK) to recreate nowadays a working dev. environment.

Comment: The direct link for the old SDK does not seem to work anymore. The EMDK for .NET is available (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/emdk-for-net.html).

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that SMDK 1.6 does not seem to be able to install on Windows 10. It keeps reporting the Visual Studio (2008, the latest one that supports .NET programming) is not found.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the broken link. I cannot find any other valid link for the SMDK.